# How to Design a web application to monitor server status in web browser

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring

I just want to try creating a web application to monitor server status. I need some design guidelines.

Should I use some scripting language like Python or ruby to get the stats? Is polling is the only way to do it? If so how frequently should we poll?

Comment: What's wrong with using `ssh` and for instance call `top`?

Comment: Take a look at [ganglia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglia_%28software%29) and in action on the [wikimedia cluster](http://ganglia.wikimedia.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about data retention, writing a simple web app in ruby or python that polls from the browser would probably be fine. You could alternately use websockets and push data from a CLI-based monitoring agent of some sort that ran in the background on your server.

If you don't care about data fidelity, then you might be able to use something simple like pingdom.

If you *do* care about data retention and you need lots of custom monitoring, then it's a much harder problem. There are a number of open source projects and paid applications that will solve this problem in various ways. As mentioned in the comment on your post, ganglia could work. You might also look into nagios or munin. If you need app level stats, you could check out statsd/graphite or influxdb/grafana.

If you want server monitoring but don't want to manage additional infrastructure, there are a lot of solutions in the paid space including librato, newrelic, and instrumental.

---

Note: I am an owner of Instrumental, so I'm biased toward that, but I think your question needs more details to narrow down any recommendations on infrastructure monitoring.

Comment: Thanks!. I'm just developing this application as an open source. I wanted to learn by doing. Hence, searched for optimal solution.

Comment: @siva  Good luck. It can be a very wide and deep problem.